# Experience Technologies field should have an indicator of how many tags I have left

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The Experience form (for lack of a better term, formlet (?)) has a Technologies field where one can list the technologies they used in a particular job. The limit is 10 apparently. Since, it's only one line and there is no count, there is no easy way to tell if I have gone over the limit until I leave that textbox. I have to use my fingers to count!

That's so primitive. All careers users would be 6.9% more efficient if there was a decrementing counter beside the field.

I.e:
[] 10 left
[c#] 9 left
[c# asp.net] 8 left

... and so on.

Comment: I agree, especially since the text box is not wide enough to see all tags at once.

Comment: Even more useful if the limit is some day increased. Seeing it suddenly at 5 when it used to be 0 is certainly more obvious than tracking the limit, counting the already used ones and doing the difference.

Comment: We'll discuss this - good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first sentence in the big yellow box to the right of the field states:

> A list of up to 10 core technologies you used on this job.

It seems fairly easy to count the tags you've entered see how close you are to 10. I can't really see how adding a count-down would help.

Comment: You've made my point for me. Why should I have to count on my fingers how many I've written down, when the site can do it for me? That's how it would help.

I know the limit is 10, but who counts as they go? People are more concerned about what they are typing, rather than how many they've typed already.